# How to access the variables defined in environment.rb in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a thread object in **environment.rb** and use it in some other action of some controller.

How should I do it?

Thanks in advance.

---

Actually, I want three processes to be running perpetually which are fetching some data and storing it in database. That's why I am using threads. Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your initial question, constants declared in environment.rb are available throughout the entire codebase. Avoid doing so if you can, though; this can become configuration spaghetti pretty quickly.

More broadly, although Rails has been (from what I understand) thread-safe since version 2.2, threads are still quite uncommon - particularly in MRI - as a way to provide concurrent operation, and MRI's green threads are anyway not particularly helpful. Consider using a message queue like [Starling](http://www.rubyinside.com/starling-and-rudeq-persistent-ruby-queues-958.html) that spins up other Ruby processes to perform asynchronous work.

Comment: Some people call it thread safe.  I wouldn't, at least not in this sense.  There are too many corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful with this.  To the best of my knowledge, rails is not thread-safe.  And trying to use threads safely in the face of all the magic (excuse me, "meta programming") it does sounds risky as all get out.

Why do you want a thread object anyway?

In response to the comment, saying rails is thread safe [might not mean as much as you think](http://m.onkey.org/2008/10/23/thread-safety-for-your-rails).  I's certainly be leery of counting on it at if I didn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Further to what Brian says, consider using an initializer (put in config/initializers to have it executed). I think it makes the intent more clear than using environment.rb.